# Qt Dynamically display text file

Tags: c++, qt

So my question is quite simple.

I have a log file which is getting written continuously. I want to display this file dynamically in a simple qt textBrowser.

So I had the idea to refresh every x seconds, but I find this a little bit dirty.
So I would like to find a light way to detect a change in the text file and then to refresh my display.

Any advice or clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the QFileSystemWatcherClass.

Set it up to monitor the log file and it will send a message each time the file is updated. You can then update your view. Happiness will ensue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the file system watcher class, you can simply track the log file size for changes every X seconds, and reload only if the size has changed. This way you can even only load the extra data that was added since the last update.